# LED bulbs won't screw in far enough

Tags: electrical, led

My led bulbs will not screw far enough in my regular light socket. I am considering adding a small circular magnet to the base of the LED before screwing into the socket to add additional length to the bulb base. Is this safe?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this -- it'll expose some of the threads on the bulb, which are connected to the neutral.  (It's a good way to get bit if you need to change the bulb again.)

An E26 to E26 extender should fix this without causing any safety issues.  You can also try turning the power off at the breaker and bending the back (hot) contact of the bulb base up with a wooden tongue depressor or other suitably nonconductive instrument so that it makes contact with the hot contact on the bulb.

Comment: I just had this exact issue with bulb lights in outdoor weather proof holders. Tweaking the contact worked perfectly